# apt-get upgrade breaks, how to get more information about the issue?

Tags: apt

When doing `sudo apt-get upgrade` it's been some weeks or more I had seen this message, but I did not pay attention to it, because I was no longer using this app `exercism` for months.

```
Illegal option -d
Usage: install [<option>...] [<path>]
Install exercism client to <path>. Default:
```

But now it gets really annoying because it impeaches me to install postgresql-9.6

when I perform `sudo apt-get upgrade` here's the log I have.
It is as if exercism the `install` command bypassing every others. Well that's the way I understand it.

```
Setting up postgresql-common (182.pgdg14.04+1) ... 
Illegal option -d Usage: install [<option>...] [<path>]
Install exercism client to <path>. Default:
  * determined interactively if possible   
  * /usr/local/bin if run as root   
  * /usr/local/bin if it is writable   
  * /home/code/bin otherwise 
Options:   
  -v <version>           Install client version <version>.      Default: v2.4.0   
  -o <operating system> Install client for <operating system>. Default: linux   
  -a <architecture>      Install client for <architecture>.     Default: 64bit 

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-common (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 64 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-9.6:  postgresql-9.6 depends on postgresql-common (>= 171~); however:   Package postgresql-common is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.6 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql:  postgresql depends on postgresql-9.6; however:   Package postgresql-9.6 is not configured yet.
```

How can I determine which command called by apt-get update is causing the problem, so as to determine what exercism has corrupted in my system. That's my hypothesis.

Unfortunately I did not install `exercism` with `checkinstall`, so I cannot do `dpkg -r exercism` to remove it safely from my system. That's a shame, I always do it normally...

Is there a way for apt-get to indicate me what command is failing at this moment ? It just says "Illegal option -d"... but that's insufficient to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log, explicitely refering to `install`:

```
Illegal option -d
Usage: install [<option>...] [<path>]
```

I interpreted that `install` was behaving strangely.

So as to know which executable was called indeed, in the shell I asked:

```
which install
```

The result was that it was not `/usr/bin/install` that was being called, but `/usr/local/bin/install`.

I renamed `/usr/local/bin/install` to `/usr/local/bin/install_exercism` and everything went well.

```
which install
```

now refers normally to `/usr/bin/install`

and Postgresql installs nicely, without anymore error messages.

Comment: This is a *very* specific Q&A — to make it more useful, could you provide more detail on the actual process you went through to figure out the error? For example, when you say “from the logs”, which logs are you referring to?

Comment: @StephenKitt I have edited a little. What do you think ?